# Simultaneous Requests in Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am learning web scraping for a hobby project (Using Selenium in python).

I'm trying to get the information on product listings . There are about a 100 web pages , and I am sequentially loading each , processing the data in each then moving to the next.
This process takes over 5 minutes with the major bottleneck being the loading time of each page.

As I am only "reading" from the pages (not interacting with any of them)... I would like to know is it possible to send requests for all the pages together(as opposed to waiting for one page to load, then requesting the next page) and process the data as they arrive.

PS: Please tell me if there are some other solutions to reduce the loading time

Comment: Look into [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/). This and an html parser (e.g. bs4) should be enough if you do not interact with javascript. If you do, try [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Python Requests Module](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) and the [built-in threading module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) to make it faster. So for example:

```py
import threading
import requests

list_of_links = [
    # All your links here
]

threads = []

all_html = {
    # This will be a dictionary of the links as key and the HTML of the links as values
}


def get_html(link):
    r = requests.get(link)
    all_html[link] = r.text


for link in list_of_links:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=get_html, args=(link,))
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)
   
for t in threads:
    t.join()
    
print(all_html)

print("DONE")
```